# Using an Kinect avatar in a 3d environment

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, kinect

I wanted to know whether it would be possible for me to have an interactive avatar in a 3d environment ? , is there anything out there to guide me towards doing this ?

Answer (score 1):

Start with the official documentation. Microsoft made an awesome job with the Kinect SDK.
[You can find it here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/).

For you question, you should check the [Avateering sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131041.aspx).

[image]